# How to integrate GTFS-realtime data with Directions service - Google map javascript API?

Tags: google-maps

Direction service API doesn't list any option to include GTFS-realtime data. Here is the link for that API - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions
Is there any way by which we can pass parameters to DirectionsRequest object and get GTFS-real time data with the result ?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible. According to [Google Transit Partner Program](https://maps.google.com/help/maps/mapcontent/transit/index.html): "The Transit on Google Maps feature is available on selected mobile devices through Google Maps for mobile."